# normalising data with combineLatest not working as expected on Angular, RxJS

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

While trying to normalize data before combining it in a new stream, changes did not occur.

I want to check if the post is liked by the user through a Promise function before returning it to the Posts Observable.

```
this.data$ = combineLatest([
      // stream 1 - posts
      this.posts_service.posts$ as Observable<Post[]>,
      // stream 2 - user
      this.user_service.user$ as Observable<_User>,
    ]).pipe(
      map(([posts, user]) => {
        // if there is a user, check if they have liked the post
        if (user) {
          // check if user has liked post
          posts = posts.map((post) => {
            // send post and user id to a promise function that will return a boolean
            this.posts_service.hasLikedPost(post, user.uid).then((has_like) => {
              console.count('hasLikedPost');
              post.has_like = has_like;
            });
            return post;
          });
          user = user;
          console.table(posts);
          return { posts, user };
        } else {
          return { posts };
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: I assume that `this.posts_service.hasLikedPost` is async. Did you try to `await` it?

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix Promises and Observables in one stream. Convert promise `this.posts_service.hasLikedPost` to observable using `from()` function and refactor operator chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my refactor. I extracted some functionality to separate function or method `getPosts` just for cleaner code.

```js
// Typing the property for better readability and type checking
const data$: Observable<{ posts: Post[], user: _User; }> = combineLatest([
    // stream 1 - posts
    this.postsService.posts$ as Observable<Post[]>,
    // stream 2 - user
    // assuming that user$ emits at least once, even there is no user
    this.userService.user$ as Observable<_User>,
]).pipe(
    // if there is a user, check if they have liked the post
    switchMap(([posts, user]) => user ? getLikes(posts, user) : of({ posts })),
);


function getLikes(posts: Post[], user: _User): Observable<{ posts: Post[], user: _User; }> {
    // create event from each post because we need to check asynchronously each one post for "has_like" flag
    return from(posts).pipe(
        // check each post if it is liked by user and add property to one
        concatMap(post => from(this.postsService.hasLikedPost(post, user.uid))
            .pipe(
                map(hasLike => ({ ...post, hasLike }))
            )
        ),
        // merge back all the posts into array
        toArray(),
        // DEBUG
        tap(posts => console.table(posts)),
        // add user to replay
        map(posts => ({ posts, user })),
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Somehow I did this it returned me only the first array.

Comment: I managed to get all the Arrays back by changing the switchMap in the getLikes function to contcatMap. But, the DOM is displaying without the updated "hasLike", while in the console.table() is hows the "hasLike" has been successfully updated.

Comment: @syahiruddin you are right, there should be concatMap or mergeMap instead of switchMap. I edited the sample. Probably DOM is not updated because Angular change detection did not detected changes.

Comment: Sorry, the DOM is not getting it because I was using a different "hasLIke" as is declared has_like" lol. Thank you, I will make yours as answer!